# Grabbing the rgb of a UIColor of a UINavigationController with translucent = YES

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, rgb, uicolor

How do I grab the RGB of a UINavigationBar in ios 7. I have set the RGB to 0, 0, 0 but its not pure black since ios 7 sets a translucency.

How do I get the real color so I can create images for my toolbars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set translucent property NO If you do not need it.

`[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTranslucent:NO];`

Comment: do i have to set it on all viewDidLoad?

Comment: No need of setting it in all.Coz you are sharing the same navigation bar throughout. Setting in Root view is fine

Answer (score 1):

Remove translucent property of navigationBar -

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```